# edit html of wordpress and applying js code-> defer images

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I want to edit this site  : 
https://beansandbriff.com/ 
which contain of many pages which you can see if you scrolled to the bottom. every page contain many images. 
all the images of all pages are loaded when the site is load which cause the site load slowly if I increased the number of images. 
I have awesome code that can defer images:
https://varvy.com/pagespeed/defer-images.html
and I know html and JS very well but I don't have experience in WP .
so my ask how I can implement this code to the site ?
I searched a lot and it seems very complicated and sometimes find who say I can't edit html code !!
so if anyone can help I 'll be very grateful 
thanks

Comment: There are plenty of Wordpress plugins that specialise in lazy loading images, maybe that’s an alternative solution

Comment: thanks Lars. I read about these plugins before but the writer of the subject that I provided the like above mentioned that it sometimes has issues and I trying to avoid that . beside his code is very small and nice . it 'll be better from the plugins I think

Answer (score 0):

As the author of the article suggests:

> put the script right before the end body tag in your html

To do this, in WordPress Dashboard, go to Appearance >> Editor and edit your  Theme Footer file (footer.php). Put the script before the `</body>`